# Amides from carboxylic acid and ammonia?

Tags: synthesis, amides

Would it be possible to synthesize amide by simply reacting carboxylic acid with ammonia and then driving off water at higher temperatures? Or would ammonia be also driven off in the process?

Google says that this should be possible, but I'm aware that some water based inks work by having ammonia neutralized acid polymer (polymer with COOH groups), then on drying the ammonia will leave thus leaving resin that will not solubilize in water again. For example styrene-co-acrylic acid and ammonia.

Thanks

Comment: It is not a very good process as you tend to just form the ammonium salt of the carboxylic acid. To get decent yields you have to activate the acid first.

Comment: @Waylander: I agree with Waylander. Best example is an amino acid, which exists as a Zwitterion in aqueous solutions.

Comment: Yes, [phthalimide is prepared in this way](https://imgur.com/rOJZV7T).